# Intermittent error calling Rest API Unable to read data from the transport connection

Tags: .net, f#, httpclient

I have some F# code that used to work and has just stopped working. The behaviour is intermittent and occurring in 2 different places. In both places it is using HttpClient ( although one is a library ). It can happen at any point in the code - after 3-4 times,  or after 20 times. I am using .Net 6 - but I get the same behaviour with .Net 7 .  It doesn't matter too much what the code is - it is calling REST APIs ( one in the cloud and one local ) .

```
System.IO.IOException
  HResult=0x80131620
  Message=Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request..
  Source=System.Net.Sockets
  StackTrace:
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in System.Net.Sockets\Socket.cs:line 499

Inner Exception 1:
SocketException: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
```

This is the Socket.cs method that throws the error.

```
private void ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (error == SocketError.OperationAborted || error == SocketError.ConnectionAborted)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
    throw CreateException(error, forAsyncThrow: false);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that the server is timing out? Can you check the server logs to see if they responded to these requests?

Comment: What's your F# code to this issue?

Comment: It is kind of odd..  I actually rewrote the code from scratch in a different solution and it works fine.  One was calling a Xero API ( using their .Net Library )  and the other a Magento API ( using HttpClient directly )   .